# URL connection crashing app after timeout

Tags: java, android, xml, urlconnection, connection-timeout

I am developing an android app in which `XML request` is sent to server and response obtained is used in app for further processing.  The problem is that the `app crashes` after request `timeout` if server is not running.  I want to show Toast about error that the "SERVER IS NOT RUNNING".  Can anybody help?

```
            try{
            URL url = new URL(server_URL); 

            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);


            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
            wr.write( 
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx XML REQUEST xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    ); 
            wr.flush(); 


             BufferedReader reader;
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;


          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
              {
                     // Append server response in string
                     sb.append(line + "\n");
              }


               data = sb.toString();


                  reader.close();

        } catch(IOException ex)
          {

            Toast.makeText(c, "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should surely be because you are running the network requests or operations on the main Thread. Are you using a sub thread or even an Async Task?

Network operations are usually done using async Tasks or through sub threads.

try Doing like so:

```
  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> aTask = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>()
    {
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute()
    {
       //task to run before main network operations start
    }
      @Override
      protected void doInBackground(Void ... s )
     {
        //all the operations to perform should go here
      }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute()
     {
       //called when operations have finished and the onBackgroun
     }
    }
```

this approach is for running network based operations using an Async Task.
No Toasts are allowed in the doInBackground method. since this is a background task, it is not allowed to interfere with the main UI context because it can cause it to hook and hinder the ui or even crash it.

Comment: I was running network request in `Async Task` but I was calling Toast.show() in `doInBackground()` method.After I removed it from there and added in `onPostExecute()` method it worked! Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Change your catch to this:

```
 catch(Exception ex)
      {
       if (ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) //time out
            Toast.makeText(c, "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace. Because it's not crashing because of the task since it has a try/catch